# MVC - Clearing sessions when publish

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, visual-studio-2017

I just want to ask is there any way to clear all sessions when I publish my project to server IIS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Restart the app pool. You can do this using powershell using the [Restart-WebAppPool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/webadminstration/restart-webapppool?view=winserver2012-ps) command. If its a remote server, which I'm guessing it is, you can either use [Enter-PSSession](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/running-remote-commands?view=powershell-6#start-an-interactive-session) or [Invoke-Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/running-remote-commands?view=powershell-6#run-a-remote-command) to run commands on the server.

Comment: So, Is there any way to automate it with visual studio publish ?

Comment: Well normally in a commercial environment these days you'd be using a CI server such as Team City or Azure DevOps (formally VSTS) that would have steps to deploy to the server and thats where you'd put these commands..... There is the concept of post publish events in visual studio, but it's been a while since I've used those.